# httpd plugin in ionic capacitorJS

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

We are working ionic capacitors hybrid mobile app.

This project ionic cordova later we convert ionic capacitor project with latest version
ionic cordova we used this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/http

```
import { Httpd, HttpdOptions } from '@ionic-native/httpd/ngx';

const options: HttpdOptions = {
      www_root: dirpath,                      //storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.test.testapp/files/website/
      port: 9000,
      localhost_only: true,
    };

this.httpd.startServer(options).subscribe((url) => {})
```

But now we are working on ionic with capacitorsJs, so we need plugin for internal startServer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@Capacitor/Http](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/http) plugin instead.

Comment: thanks for reply . am not seeing any API for startServer in CapacitorHttp